# C++ type of item

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;

class SimpleProduct {
    char look = 'x';
    string name = "Undefined";
    string type = "Undefined";
    string description = "Undefined";
public:
    char getLook() const {return look;}
    string getType() const {return type;}
    string getName() const {return name;}
    string getDescription() const {return description;}
    SimpleProduct(char look = 'x', string &&name = "Undefined", string &&type = "Undefined", string &&description = "Undefined");
    virtual string toString() const;
};

class TallProduct : public SimpleProduct {
public:
    TallProduct(char look, string &&name = "Undefined", string &&type = "Undefined", string &&description = "Undefined");
    string toString() const;
};
```

All of products are saved in attribute `unique_ptr<Product> ***products;` of another class and I want to check, whether some specific product is type Product or TallProduct.

So for example:

```
if (y != 0 && products[x][y-1][position] is type TallProduct) {  //pseudocode
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you're using GCC you have the `typeof` operator. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html - Furthermore there is `typeid`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/

Comment: Can you change the class definition? You could add a virtual bool method returning false in the base class and true in the derived class.

Comment: `unique_ptr<Product> ***products;` Please don't be a three star programmer.  Build a NDMatrix class that uses a single dimension vector under the hood so you can have RAII semantics.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: Are you sure you want to take `string&&`s?

Comment: @FinnRayment Isn't `typeof` static? The docs you linked to says it gives the type of an expression, not the dynamic type of an object.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Oups! Indeed it does. I retract half of my statement.

Comment: Since products are unique pointers, could I do something like this?
`products[x][y-1][position].get() == TallProduct`
What syntax should I use here to say that I want to compare it name of the type? Simple 'TallProduct' is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `dynamic_cast<>`, you can check if type is something specific **if it is inherited and it is polymorphic**.

Here is a small sample:

```
class A {
    public:
    virtual ~A() {};
};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};

int main() {
    A* b = new B();
    C* c = new C();
    std::cout << (dynamic_cast<B*>(b) != nullptr) << "\n";
    std::cout << (dynamic_cast<B*>(c) != nullptr) << "\n";
}
```

which creates following output:

```
1
0
```

That means `b` is from type `B` but `c` is not.

Comment: @MikeVine yea,just noticed. upading my answer that it works on polymorphic classes.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work, you need to do two things:

1. Add at least one virtual function to your SimpleProduct, so that the hierarchy gets a vtable. You want the virtual destructor here, so that `unique_ptr` will do it's job properly: `virtual ~SimpleProduct() = default`
2. Check the conversion with the pointer-variant of dynamic_cast, i.e. `auto tallProduct = dynamic_cast<TallProduct*>(products[x][y-1][position]);` You can proceed if the pointer is not `nullptr`

Note that this is generally considered **bad style**, because it violates the "Tell, don't ask" mantra of OOP

Comment: Should this do a thing?

`auto tallProduct = dynamic_cast<TallProduct*>(products[x][y-1][position]);
    if (y != 0 && typeof(tallProduct) == TallProduct) {
        return 0;
    }`

Comment: For this, you want `if (y != 0 && tallProduct != nullptr) { return 0; }`